# Is it possible to enable and disable captcha for different web services?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to allow users to self register with ask password option using web services.I am also using captcha Verification ,when the users registers.

So once they register ,i send a mail with confirmation code ,username and tenant domain for updating the password.

I am trying to do this update password without a captcha.But seems i cannot update to confirm the verification code without having a captcha.

Is it possible to enable and disable captcha for different web services or is there any ways to activate and update the password of the account without captcha in wso2 5.1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the captcha verification as follows.

Captcha.Verification.Internally.Managed=true

But, it will disable the captcha verification in every methods userInfoRecovery service and ask password feature. It is not possible to disable captcha from one service.

Admin user can lock/unlock users through management console. That you will be able to activate users. [1]

[1] http://isurad.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-lock-user-account-in-wso2.html

Comment: Thanks.Was checking whether wso2 can provide option to enable and disable captcha per web service.